# How come my buttons aren't displaying on canvas

Tags: javascript, button, canvas

My html code below should display a button for the colors green and red but they are not displaying, I do however see the buttons for clear canvas and howdy. any help on what is wrong? I would ultimately like when the buttons are pushed to changed the color of the line that is beign drawn on the canvas, I fanyone knows how ti implement in Javascript code that owuld be helpful. I'm very new to this.

```
<title>Paint Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="300">
            <input type= "button" value= "Green" id= "green" onclick= "GreenRect()" />
            <input type= "button" value= "Red" id= "red" onclick= "RedRect()" />
            </p>
        </canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src=".js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<body >
    <button id="clear">Clear Canvas</button><br>
    <button id="howdy">Howdy!</button><br>
</body>
```

Comment: I believe that anything within the canvas element is hidden _unless_ the browser in question isn't HTML5 savvy and doesn't understand the `<canvas>` element. As such, it is often the case that websites will put a nice little "Your browser cannot properly render the canvas element" message in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons should be below canvas in you code, just because canvas ignore all content within opening and closeing tags.

You can style your buttons position to have overlayed canvas.

Btw. you have double `<body>` tag in your code.

Comment: Now I actually jus thav to get it to actually change the color when the button is clicked.

Comment: Try to use `onclick` event and change css class (or just style) when event was fired. P.S. Best thanks is accepting the answer ;)

Comment: Yeah I know. I had to wait a certain amount of minutes to accept.